# Open item with context menu action

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and java and I'm trying to work on an app.

The reason I'm seeking for help is that I can't figure out how to replicate the action of single tapping on an item of a list (action that opens the item) in a context menu (which appears with a long tap on the item). I can't associate the field I created ("Modify item") to actually open the selected item. I can't post any part of the code and I'm sorry about that, hope you might understand and help anyways.
Thanks

Comment: It would be great if you show us how do you creating the context menu's items

Comment: The context menu fields are basically switch cases, every case corresponding to an action to perform on the item. For example i have "case ApplicationConstant.MODIFY_ITEM: " and then the code i need to actually open and modify the item (these items are compiled forms someone might modify)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.